# Вывести из базы MySQL в виде json массива

Tags: json, php, mysql

Здравствуйте! Нужно с помощью php реализовать вывод json массива, визуальный его вид такой:

```
{"akk":[["1","Dmitry","Novickov"],["2","Evgenuy","Novickov"]]}
```

Нужно выводить именно таким JSON массивом.. Пожалуйста помогите это реализовать.

Comment: Повторю: вам нужно просто разобраться с тем, как php-функция json_encode преобразует массивы в json. Чтобы получился js-массив, исходный массив должен быть индексированным, если исходный был ассоциативным, получится js-объект.

Comment: Так помогите тогда пожалуста.. я тут новенький и вовсе глуп..

Comment: документацию почитать - видимо не судьба..

Comment: VenZell , а мне надо так же само только с mySQL базы..

Comment: Вы же получаете какой-то массив, делая запрос к базе данных? Ну так и преобразуйте его в json-формат. Или, если не можете сами, покажите массив и мы поможем вам.

Answer (score 1):

А в чем сложность?

```
$array = array(
    'akk' => array(
        array(1, 'Dmitry', 'Novickov'),
        array(2, 'Evgenuy', 'Novickov')
    )
);
echo json_encode($array);
//Выведет: {"akk":[[1,"Dmitry","Novickov"],[2,"Evgenuy","Novickov"]]}
```